# btnSubmit_Click skipping try and going straight to catch (Exception ex)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have two near identical forms on the site and only one of them works.  On firing button click they're supposed to collect text from checkbox fields and email that information on.  One of the forms try is completely ignored and the error message in catch is displayed

Using the working form on the new page still won't work makes me think there may be issues with the page, but deleting the aspx and aspx.cs pages and rewriting them when it may not be that serious is not something I want to do if it's not necessary.  I've tried removing 'if (IsPostBack)' and 'if      (LiabilityCheckBox.Checked == true)' on the form with issues among other things, but nothing seems to help.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (LiabilityCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            // validate the Captcha to check we're not dealing with a bot
            bool isHuman = ExampleCaptcha.Validate(CaptchaCodeTextBox.Text);
            CaptchaCodeTextBox.Text = null; // clear previous user input
            if (!isHuman)
            {                
                lblCaptchaError.Visible = true;
                lblCaptchaError.Text = "Incorrect Code.  Please try again!";
            }
            else
            {                
                try
                {
                    //some code
                    lblRegMessage.Text = 
                        ("Registration Successful. Thank you for entering."         
                        + "Please click button below to finalise Payment and Registration.");

                    // Clear the textbox values
                    //Show Continue Button.
                    ContinueButton.Visible = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = ("Your registration failed to send, please try again");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ("You must check the Liability check box to continue");
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the result of filling out the form to be the mail is sent and a message appears telling the user "Registration Successful. Thank you for entering."

What I am getting is this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblMessage.Text = ("Your registration failed to send, please try again");
}
```

Comment: Looks like another exception is thrown before your "try" block is reached. It would be helpful to see the exception message.

Comment: The only exception message Is catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = ("Your registration failed to send, please try again");
                        }

Comment: @BenWood - that's not what the exception message is. The exception message is located in the `Message` property of the `Exception` object, which in this case would be the value of `ex.Message`.

Comment: Is there any way that this can be fixed, or will I have to delete the entire page and start again?  What would have caused such a thing to happen in this form and not the other which is almost identical on another page>

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `if (IsPostBack)`. Also put a breakpoint on the first line of **all** `catch` blocks. Now, run to the first breakpoint. Step **line by line**. At some point you will jump to a `catch` block. What line was it on **immediately prior** to jumping to the `catch` block?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but visual studio is not stopping at breakpoints.  Even when I don't add breakpoints on the lines you suggested, but start on if(IsPostBack) for example it keeps going and going and going with no result

Comment: Are you running debug or release builds? Are you saying breakpoints don't work **anywhere at all**? Or just in this specific code?

Comment: I am running debug builds and they are not responding as expected anywhere at all.  I have done some research since a debug was suggested and there seems to be an issue with VS not stopping at breakpoints with others as well.

Answer (score -1):

As I checked, your code missing some closing brackets. Please check the brackets are properly closed and in the series.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did not add the entire code.  Just the blocks I thought were relevant so it's quite understandable there may be a bracket missing here and there.

Comment: Debug the code and check the exception, what error is there. May be some runtime error in the code

Comment: I get two inner exceptions, both on smtp.Send(msg); (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail.') inside the try block.  The first is: WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server.  The second is: SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 203.89.213.170:25
.  This is worrying as I have another near identical form on the site and have never had any issues with it for years.

Comment: Your SMTP server gives error while sending email from this form. Please check all the details of SMTP **(server, Username, Password, Port)**

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried moving away from my hosting company's mail server and using "smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";" and port numbers 25/465/587 and I get the same result every time.  FAIL!  If I leave "smtp.Send(Msg);" out of the code the program runs as expected, but obviously no mail arrives.  When I put it back in it skips the try block where the mail code is all together and goes straight to the catch block.  Odd thing is I have another identical form (but with a few extra text boxes) on the site which has never given me any grief.

Comment: Which email are you using in From and To. please try with email of gmail